# Special Character gets encoded while editing in XPM

Tags: 2013, experience-manager

If we add any special character like "å ä ö å ä ö å ä ö" anywhere on site then those character displays as it is but if we are try to do editing in XPM and select any field or paragraph in XPM mode then those special characters get encoded. below is the screen shot before and after character get encoded.

[image]
[image]
We already verify the few things like

- Publication Target is set to UTF-8.
- Browser character setting.
- website's web.config has following.

< globalization fileEncoding="UTF-8" requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" />

But still encoding is happening only when trying to do editing in XPM.

Screenshot of the Odata Service.
[image]

Comment: Did you check the encoding settings of the odata service?

Comment: Even odata service encoding settings are UTF-8, but still getting the same issue, added the screenshot for odata service.

Comment: @Nash - Before this question is re-opened, have you tried the `-DFile.encoding` setting of the Deployer (within the registry) as outlined in Bart's answer in the duplicate question?